# About the object of a verb followed by "to"

Tags: objects, indirect-objects

In the sentence "He sang to himself." is the pronoun `himself` the indirect object pf the verb `sang`? Or is the phrase `to himself` the (indirect) object of the verb `sang`?

Answer (score 3):

In the sentence:

- I sang Mary a song

The first Object, *Mary*, is the Indirect Object—the person that 'gets' the song. The phrase *a song* is the Direct Object—the thing being given. If we change the order of Mary and the song, the grammar changes:

- I sang a song to Mary.

In the example above, *a song* is still a Direct Object, but the preposition phrase *to Mary* is not an Indirect Object.  We describe it as a Complement of the verb *sing*. [Notice that *to Mary* does not get the song!]

Inside this preposition phrase, the word *Mary* is the Complement of the preposition *to*. It is not an Object or Complement of the verb. It is a Complement of the preposition.

In the Original Poster's example:

> He sang to himself.

The verb *sang* has no Objects. It only has a prepositional Complement.

As a general rule of thumb a preposition phrase will usually be a Complement of the verb (maybe a Predicative Complement, or a Locative Complement). But it will very rarely be the Direct or Indirect Object of the verb.

One test we can do to see if a phrase is a Direct Object, or perhaps an Indirect Object, is to see if we can passivise the sentence by making that phrase the Subject of a passive sentence:

- Mary was sung a song.
- *To Mary was sung a song. (ungrammatical)
- *To him was sung the song. (ungrammatical)
- *To himself was sung the song. (ungrammatical)

In the rare cases where a preposition phrase *is* the Object of a verb, we will usually be able to passivise it:

- We judged after Christmas to be the best time for the party.
- After Christmas was judged to be the best time for the party.

Comment: I liked the passivisig technique. Though I don't understand how it works with _"I gave a book to him"_.  Based on the technique, _"*to him was given a book"_ is ungrammatical but _him_ is the _indirect object_ of the sentence isn't it?

Comment: @Azad Not exactly. In "They gave him a book", the string "him" is the IO. But in "They gave a book to him" the word *him* is the Complement of the preposition *to* and the string *to him* is the prepositional Complement of the verb *gave*. Notice that we can passivise the first sentence like this "He was given a book". Am I making sense?

Comment: Yea, I see your point. With this, we're left with just one possible place for IO in a sentence which is right after the verb and before the DO. Then I guess we can say in _"I give a book to him"_, _him_ is the _object of preposition_ (OP) not the DO. Then the same is true about 'sing to himself'. _Himself_ is the OP here not the IO.

Comment: @Azad It may help to look at the section "**Verbs with direct and indirect objects**" [in this page from Cambridge Dictionaries](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/verb-patterns-with-and-without-objects). If you look under the fourth example, you'll see it says "*Prepositional complements can operate as an alternative to indirect objects with some of these verbs*" It then gives some examples. :)

Comment: @Azad Yes, that's exactly right.

Answer (score 1):

First:

An indirect object is going to be the second of two objects.  There's only a few verbs that take two objects in English, *give* and *bring* being common ones.

Since there's one object here, it's a direct object.  Indirect objects will be preceded by *to* sometimes, but direct objects won't.

Second:

A verb's object is something/someone integral to the action and meaning that the verb expresses.  Some verbs really need objects, some can let context fill in an object, and some change meaning without objects.

> I hit the table. (The thing that I hit was the table.)
>
> I hit. (*Hit* really needs an object.  Listener/reader is going to immediately ask "You hit what?" - even with strong context this sounds incomplete.)
>
> I sang "Mary had a little lamb." (The song (object) that I sang was "Mary had a little lamb".)
>
> I sang. (*Sing* without an object can mean *to sing regularly*.  If previous context was talking about a specific song, listener/reader will assume that is what you are singing.)

Now, for most verbs you can attach a prepositional phrase expressing how or in what direction the activity was performed.  *To* can be one of these prepositions - but keep in mind *to* has many different meanings in English - one is indicating the infinitive, other is indicating the indirect object, and another is synonymous somewhat with *toward* or *at*.

> I sang "Mary had a little lamb" to my cat.  (The song (object) that I sang was "Mary had a little lamb" and this activity was directed towards my cat.)

When you do this, this is *not* an object.  Because the meaning of the verb doesn't change if you remove it.

> I gave the ball to Mary.
>
> I gave the ball. (Listener/reader will wonder who you gave the ball to.  Sounds incomplete.  *Give* with 1 object means *donate* or *donate blood* and a ball is not something typically donated.)
>
> I gave $20. (Sounds like you donated something at church.  Doesn't sound wrong.)

So, *myself* cannot be the object of *I sing* unless you are a song.

> I sang to myself.  (You are singing and directing that activity towards yourself.  You could mean *sing* intransitively as in *to sing regularly* or there is a song mentioned previously that context would fill in.)

But:

> I sang myself.  (Looking at the words, this makes "myself" the object of "I sang" - meaning it can look like you think that you are a song.  However, since this doesn't make sense, it equates to "I sang BY myself.")